# entity framework filter logical deleted records

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF 5.0 and Code First. In my generic repository I have a method for exclude records in a logical way. This method actually perform a update, setting the status of the entity field to false.

I would like to intercept my queries, and filter only where status == true.

Is there a easy way to do that?  Ex:

```
new GenericRepository<Entity>().ToList(); 
// and internally it will filter where status == true.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a generic method

```
public IQueryable<T> All<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {

  return context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);

}
```

and if you want something more linked to your `status` property, you have to use reflection and build the Lambda by yourself (as you can't use interfaces with linq to entites queries).

Something like that (untested), calling the generic `All` method.

```
   public IQueryable<T>AllButDeleted<T>() {
     var property = typeof(T).GetProperty("status");
     //check if T has a "status" property
     if (property == null && || property.PropertyType != typeof(bool)) throw new ArgumentException("This entity doesn't have an status property, or it's not a boolean");
     //build the expression
     //m =>
      var parameter = new ParameterExpression(typeof(T), "m");
     // m.status
     Expression body = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
     //m.status == true (which is just m.status)
     body = Expression.IsTrue(body);
     //m => m.status
     var lambdaPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, new[]{parameter});
     return All(lambdaPredicate);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make all your entities implement some `IDeletable` interface:

```
public interface IDelitable
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; }
}
```

And add constraint to generic parameter of your repository

```
public class GenericRepository<T>
   where T: class, IDelitable
```

And add filter when you are returning values:

```
context.Set<T>().Where(e => !e.IsDeleted)
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus no, it works just fine. Because it doesn't know anything about interfaces of entity - it works with implementation.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I completely sure it will not, because just verified this code with EF5 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it using Where.

```
.Where(e => e.Status == true).ToList();
```